# Determining even/odd numbers (integers)?

Tags: android, math

I feel stupid asking such a simple question, but is there an easy way to determine whether an Integer is even or odd?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not android specific, but a standard function would be:

```
boolean isOdd( int val ) { return (val & 0x01) != 0; }
```

Many compilers convert modulo (`%`) operations to their bitwise counterpart automatically, but this method is also compatible with older compilers.

Answer (score 42):

```
if ((n % 2) == 0) {
    // number is even
}

else {
    // number is odd
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [modular division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java) (technically in Java it acts as a strict remainder operator; the link has more discussion):

```
if ( ( n % 2 ) == 0 ) {
    //Is even
} else {
    //Is odd
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do a bitwise-and with `1`, you can detect whether the least significant bit is 1.  If it is, the number is odd, otherwise even.

In C-ish languages, `bool odd = mynum & 1;`

This is faster (performance-wise) than `mod`, if that's a concern.

Comment: wouldn't even be true when mynum is odd?

Comment: I think this is flawed. You need to rename your variable to odd.

Comment: @Bill, @Anton - sorry, I had posted with the wrong sense for the result.  I thought I had edited before anyone caught me...

Answer (score 1):

When somehow `%` as an operator doesn't exist, you can use the AND operator:

```
oddness = (n & 1) ? 'odd' : 'even'
```

Comment: yeah, that was a typo, sorry!

Comment: shouldn't it be double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to others, but here's how I did it.

```
boolean isEven = i %2 ==0;
```