# What does comment.charAt(i % comment.length()) do?

Tags: java, variables

I don't understand the `% comment.length` bit of the following code:

```
comment.charAt(i % comment.length())
```

Does the part between the brackets convert to an integer with the value that represents `i` in relation to the comment length?

For instance, if:

```
comment = "test"
i = 2
```

what would `comment.charAt(i % comment.length())` be?

Comment: 2%4 => 2. And character at index 2 is **s**. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Well, you're basically saying `comment.charAt(0.5)`, which doesn't work as the `charAt()` method takes only positive integers as its argument.

Comment: @fireshadow52 - Might want to [re-calculate that](https://www.google.com/search?q=2+%25+4).

Comment: %fireshadow52: no % is not the division operator is the modulo operator and works on integers

Comment: @RobHruska Right... I forgot the modulo operator only returned integers. Well in that case, the result would be "s".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java is relevant.

Answer (score 6):

% is the modulo operator, thus for your example `i % comment.length()` would resolve to `2 % 4 = 2`. This would return the third character (at index 2).

The modulo operation seems to be a safeguard for cases where `i >= comment.length()`.

Consider the following case: `i = 11` and `comment = "test"`. 
If you just use `comment.chatAt(i)` you'd get an exception since there are only 4 characters. The modulo operation would wrap that around and result in `11 % 4 = 3` and return the fourth character (index 3) in that case.

Comment: Thanks! I understand! It returns the remainder of the division !

so 13 % 3 = 1, 5 % 3 = 2, 5 % 2 = 1 and so on.

Comment: Exactly! If you like this answer... you should choose it!

Answer (score 2):

`%` is the modulo operator: it gives you the remainder of an integer division

```
10 % 3 = 1
```

as `10 / 3 = 3` with a remainder of `1`

Your statement just ensures that the function argument will be less then the string length.

**But** I would rather check this in another way. It is pretty counterintuitive to ask for character at position 11 in a string long 10 characters and get the character at position 1 instead of a warning or error message.