# Why cant I assign a remainder to a new variable??? JAVA

Tags: java, operators, modulo, modulus

```
    int d = year%100;
    int c = year/100;
    int valueA = (int)(((13*monthnumber)-1)/5);
    int valueB = (int) d/4;
    int valueC = (int) c/4;

    int weekDay = (d + valueA + d + valueB + valueC - 2*c);

    int remainder %= weekDay/7;
```

im trying to use the modulus assignment operator but keep getting a system error saying that an '=' was expected instead of '%='

code in question is the last line

please help

Comment: Because `%=` is invalid. You can only assign variables with "=". You're looking for `int remainder = weekDay % 7;`

Comment: Do you mean `int remainder = weekDay%7;` ? If not, what do you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the syntax for mod in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java)

Comment: oh wow, duh.sorry im running low on sleep. Thanks!

Comment: To use an operator like this, the variable has to have had a previous declaration, and a previous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just meant to do this:

```
int remainder = weekDay % 7;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int remainder %= weekDay/7;
```

would be equivalent to

```
int remainder = remainder % weekDay/7;
```

which makes no sense since you just declared `remainder`, so it has no previous value.

Had you declared the `remainder` variable earlier, this would work :

```
remainder %= weekDay/7;
```

Answer (score 2):

%= can't be used for variables that haven't had a value assigned yet.

```
var %= {value};
```

is equivalent to

```
var = var % {value};
```

But in the way you're using it, remainder hasn't had a value assigned to it yet. So it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

because with `int remainder` you are declaring a variable, and its initialisation cannot be achieved with `%=`