# with out using division operation (/) in java,find division of numbers

Tags: java

With out using division operation (`/`) in java, write a program for division of numbers.

Suppose lets consider two number `a=10` and `B=7` i want reminder to be printed in the console of the program.

Comment: `10%7`? Should google atleast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the syntax for mod in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java)

Comment: Seems homework ... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulus operator `%`

```
System.out.println(10%7);
```