# What is the percent % operator in java?

Tags: java

```
public static int sumDigits (int n) {
  if(n < 10)
    return n;
  else
    return n%10 + sumDigits (n/10);
}
```

This method is used to calculate the sum of the digits in a number recursively, but I do not understand it? What is the purpose of n%10???

Comment: n%10 returns the rest of a division by 10. example 5%10 would be 5 and 13%10 would be 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the syntax for mod in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding The Modulus Operator %](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator)

Comment: Do be aware that recursion is neither ideal nor necessary to solve this problem.  Treat this example as an academic exercise only, not as a good real-world solution. IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

`n%10` means modulus of `10`. This is used to get last digit.

Let's say your number is `12345`

`12345 % 10` means remainder when `12345` is divided by `10`, which gives you `5`.

Thereafter when you perform `(n/10)` you get `1234` (all the numbers except the least significant digit that you got in previous step).

Answer (score 3):

`n%10` gives you the least significant digit of `n` by calculating the remainder of dividing the number by 10.

Hence, the method returns the sum of the least significant digit and the sum of digits of `n/10` (which is the number that contains all the digits of `n` except of the least significant digit).

Answer (score 2):

`n%10` means the modulus of 10, that is the remainder you get when you divide with 10. Here it is used to get each digit.

Example:

Say your number is n = 752.

n%10 = 2, n/10 = 75

So you add 2 to the `sumDigits(75)`

Now, n%10 = 75%10 = 5. This is the digit to be added and so on, till your `n >= 10`. When it is `< 10`, you have a single digit that you just need to return as it is, as that is only the sum of digits in that single-digit number n.

Comment: that covers it up, nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

% is modulus, so n mod 10, it returns the remainder after n / 10.

if n is 1 to 10, then it will return 1 to 9 and 0 when n is 10.