# How to remove certain numbers using String.format()?

Tags: java, string.format

I'm working with a class called `Human` where I've defined a year to the `Human` class - the years are between 1932 and 2017 - and I would like to use `String.format()` to convert `1948` to `F48`, where the `F` is always in front. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I've been trying out:

```
String sf3 = String.format("Value is %10s", 1948);
```

But it seems only to be adding more whitespace.

Comment: Why have you been trying out `%10s` which is for padding (i.e. adds whitespace), and why are you surprised that it adds whitespace? Why would you think it might result in `F48`?

Comment: String sf3=String.format("Value is F%02d",1948%100);

Comment: By the way, you should hurry, your code will be deprecated in less than two month ;)

Comment: It was more of a lead to use the String.format(), I'm not surprised that it adds whitespace, I simply dropped that line of code to show what I've been trying out in the past.

Comment: Thank you iamnoten!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drop the first two digits, you should use the [modulo (%) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java) to get the remainder when dividing by 100. Then just prefix that with the letter "F" and you're done.

Comment: You also have to zero-pad the output of the number if it's less than 10.