# How do I break the output line after every 6 numbers? For-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

How do I make it so that it is only 6 numbers on each line when using a for-loop?
Where and how can I use the `System.out.print("\n");` ?

```
for (int i=0; i<=100; i++) {
   System.out.print(i+",");
}
```

Comment: See [`modulo syntax`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/90238/4636715)

Comment: @karanshah Breaking out of a loop is not what is asked here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%` operator to see if `i` is divisible by `6`. Since `i` starts at zero, we must check to see if the remainder is equal to `5`

```
 for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
     System.out.print(i+",");
     if(i % 6 == 5) {
        System.out.println();
     }
 }
```

The [`%`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) operator

> divides one operand by another and returns the remainder as its result.

Comment: This will print `0` on the first line, then immediately print `\n`. Change the newline condition to `i % 6 == 5`.

Answer (score 1):

I found out I could use a counter and a if

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
    counter++;
    System.out.print(i + ",");
    if(counter == 6){
        System.out.print("\n");
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java-8 IntStream and `collect`:

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
int size = 6;
int startingRange = 1;
int endingRange = 20;
IntStream.rangeClosed(startingRange, endingRange).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> atomicInteger.getAndIncrement() / size))
        .values().forEach(i -> {
            System.out.println(i.toString().replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("]", ""));
        });
```