# Using the modulo operator in java

Tags: java, modulo

I'd like to ask about using the modulus operation, could someone tell me how to use an if statement, why use [== 0], but we can assign the value from a modulus calculation into another variable.

Why does below code work?

```
     int number = 100;
        if(number % 2 == 0)
        {
             sout(number);
        }
```

and why does this one also work not using if?

```
lastDigit = number % 10;
```

why doesn't below statement work?

```
if(number % 2)
{
sout (number);
}
```

Comment: You seem to think modulo means "is x divisible by y with no remainder" - it instead means "what's the remainder if I divide x by y".

Comment: If you aren't using an IDE (such as IntelliJ or Eclipse), this would be a great time to start. In IntelliJ, this code `if (1 % 2) { }` shows an error: `Incompatible types. Required: boolean Found: int`.

Comment: There is no modulo operator in Java. This s the remainder operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the syntax for mod in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

`number % 2` is an expression that can't be evaluated to a boolean by any means.

> ### 15.17.3. Remainder Operator %
>
> The binary % operator is said **to yield the remainder of its operands from an implied division**; the left-hand operand is the dividend and the right-hand operand is the divisor.
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator returns an `int`, in this case but it could return a `double` or `long` depending on the operands. An `if` statement requires a boolean. So the reason why you can't do `if(number % 2)` is because there is no boolean. With `if(number % 2 == 0)` you are checking if the result of the modulo operator is zero, which is a boolean.

Comment: To be precise, it's not always `int`. It could be a floating-point number if operands are of such type (or, at least, one is)

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko. Great point! I should have specified that in this case it would be an int

Comment: It could also be a long. Your answer needs fixing on these points.