# How to get the even numbered options from dropdown in Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, dropdown, html-select

The first 2 options are getting printed instead of 2 and 4.

```
driver.get("http://output.jsbin.com/osebed/2/");

WebElement fruits = driver.findElement(By.id("fruits"));
Select select = new Select(fruits);
List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
int size = options.size();
System.out.println("No of options "+size);
    
for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++) {
    if(i/2==0) {
        //options.
        System.out.println(options.get(i).getText());
    }
}
```

The first 2 options are getting printed instead of 2 and 4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the syntax for mod in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

To print the even numbered `<option>` texts you can increment the counter by **2** as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<options.size(); i+2) {
    System.out.println(options.get(i).getText());
}
```